# Return values for appropriate arguments

Tags: php, mysql

Is here any possible to write single return for both $strValues and $strThumbImages i need to return $strValues for every time but returning $strThumbImages is just when it is available..

```
 function doSelectBranchRecords($objArray,$ImageId = NULL)
        {
            global $global_config;
            $strWhereClause = '';
            if ($objArray['frmNameSearch']) {
                $strWhereClause.= " AND A.branch_ident = '".$objArray['frmNameSearch']."' ";
            }
            if ($objArray['frmLoanSearch']) {
                $strWhereClause.= " AND A.loan_ident = '".$objArray['frmLoanSearch']."' ";
            }
            if ($objArray['frmBeneficiarySearch']) {
                $strWhereClause.= " AND A.beneficiary_idents = '".$objArray['frmBeneficiarySearch']."' ";
            }
            if ($objArray['frmDateSearch']) {

                $strDate = explode("-", $objArray['frmDateSearch']);
                $strAccountstarted = $strDate[2].'-'.$strDate[1].'-'.$strDate[0];

                $strWhereClause.= " AND A.account_started = '".$strAccountstarted."' ";
                /*printArray($strWhereClause); exit;*/
            }

            if ($ImageId) {

                $strThumbImages = $global_config["SiteGlobalUploadPath"].$ImageId;
                return $strThumbImages;
            }


            $strSqlSelect = "SELECT A.*,B.branch_name FROM tbl_companydetails as A,tbl_branchdetails as B where A.branch_ident=B.branch_id $strWhereClause order by company_id DESC";
            $strValues = SelectQry($strSqlSelect);
            return $strValues;

        }
```

Comment: You could make a class (object) for the branchrecords and fill it with the information from the database (making it a database acces object, or just a model). Then you can get both, if available, from that object instead of having a function return them (or trying to return them rather awkwardly in an array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Simon and @Suchit are right in that you cannot return more than one variable. But in php it is very straightforwarded to return a list with multiple items like so:

```
function getXYZ(){
  return array(4,5,6);
}

list($x,$y,$z) = getXYZ();
```

So in your case this could look like so:

```
$strThumbImages  = null;
if ($ImageId) {
  $strThumbImages = $global_config["SiteGlobalUploadPath"].$ImageId;
}
$strSqlSelect = "SELECT A.*,B.branch_name FROM tbl_companydetails as A,tbl_branchdetails as B where     A.branch_ident=B.branch_id $strWhereClause order by company_id DESC";
$strValues = SelectQry($strSqlSelect);
return array($strValues, $strThumbImages);
```

Answer (score 1):

A php function can't return more than one variable. You could get both results from the function by returning an array with either one or two keys in it, then do a check in your calling code to see what has been set. So the end of your function becomes:

```
        ...
        }

        $output = array();

        if ($ImageId) {
            $strThumbImages = $global_config["SiteGlobalUploadPath"].$ImageId;
            $output['thumbImages'] = $strThumbImages;
        }

        $strSqlSelect = "SELECT A.*,B.branch_name FROM tbl_companydetails as A,tbl_branchdetails as B where A.branch_ident=B.branch_id $strWhereClause order by company_id DESC";
        $strValues = SelectQry($strSqlSelect);
        $output['strValues'] = $strValues;
        return $output;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As above @Simon Brahan said you can not return more than one variable.

so you can use array with different keys.but you should also check if $ImageId is set and not null.

```
 if (isset($ImageId) && !is_null($ImageId)) {
            $strThumbImages = $global_config["SiteGlobalUploadPath"].$ImageId;
            $output['thumbImages'] = $strThumbImages;
        }

        $strSqlSelect = "SELECT A.*,B.branch_name FROM tbl_companydetails as A,tbl_branchdetails as B where A.branch_ident=B.branch_id $strWhereClause order by company_id DESC";
        $strValues = SelectQry($strSqlSelect);
        $output['strValues'] = $strValues;
        return $output;
```

Comment: Dude, what's this?: `if (isset($ImageId) && ImageId !='NULL')`

Comment: And you could combine it with `empty()`. Just my 2c.